Maria DB driver installation issue in RHEL Docker container
getting below error when trying to run the tableaubridge in a docker container.
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yum install -y mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.7-ga-rhel7-x86_64/*.rpm" did not complete successfully: exit code:1

getting the issue while installing the rpm package
code:
# Download the MariaDB Connector/ODBC 3.1.7 tarball
RUN wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/odbc/connector-odbc-3.1.7/mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.7-ga-rhel7-x86_64.tar.gz

# Extract the tarball
RUN tar -xzf mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.7-ga-rhel7-x86_64.tar.gz

*# Install the RPM packages*
RUN yum install -y mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.7-ga-rhel7-x86_64/*.rpm  **(in this step it is throwing error)**

# Clean up the tarball and directory
RUN rm -rf mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.7-ga-rhel7-x86_64.tar.gz mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.7-ga-rhel7-x86_64


If you download and uncompress the tarball you will notice there's no mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.7-ga-rhel7-x86_64/*.rpm so it looks like some step is missing ...

Any thoughts here for this issue

the steps for installing this specific version of the ODBC commector are here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-odbc/#installing-mariadb-connectorodbc-on-rhelcentos
